# This code keeps returning 'undefined' for (names[i]). what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, google-chrome

This code keeps returning 'undefined' for (names[i]). When I console.log() it loops through the array and prints Hello (names[i]) or Good Bye (names[i])what am I doing wrong?

```js
    (function (window) {
       var helloSpeaker = {};
       helloSpeaker.name = " ";
       var speak = "Hello";
       helloSpeaker.speak = function () {
          console.log(speak + helloSpeaker.name);
  }

  window.helloSpeaker = helloSpeaker;

})(window);

(function (window) {
    var byeSpeaker = {};
    byeSpeaker.name = " "
    var speak = "Good Bye"
    byeSpeaker.speak = function () {

     console.log(speak + byeSpeaker.name);
  }

  window.byeSpeaker = byeSpeaker;

})(window);


(function () {

    var names = ["Yaakov", "John", "Jen", "Jason", "Paul", "Frank", "Larry", "Paula", "Laura", "Jim"];

   for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
   var firstLetter = names[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase();
   if (firstLetter === 'j') {

    console.log(byeSpeaker.speak(names[i]));
  } else {
    console.log(helloSpeaker.speak(names[i]));
  }
}

})();
```

Comment: You should start by indenting your code meaningfully and consistently.  This will help you to read and understand your own code.  Please also update the question to a runnable code snippet so we can observe the problem.

Comment: Your the code instance in your question is poorly indented making it difficult to help even if we want to.

Comment: Hello, thanks for pointing that out. i just edited it. hope its easier to read now

Comment: @ThatLady: Your `speak()` functions don't return anything.  So at the very end of the code when you log their return values to the console, you're logging `undefined` to the console.  *Either* log the value in the function *or* return the value from the function and log it at the end.  Not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're passing the name in as an argument to the `speak` function, however, in your definition of `speak` it doesn't take an argument at all.

You can fix it by defining it like this:

```
helloSpeaker.speak = function (name) {
  console.log(speak + name);
}
byeSpeaker.speak = function (name) {
   console.log(speak + name);
}
```

Also, here I cleaned up the logic for you.

```
(function () {
  class Speaker {
    constructor(greeting) {
      this.greeting = greeting;
    }
    speak(name) {
      return `${this.greeting}, ${name}`;
    }
  }

  const helloSpeaker = new Speaker('Hello');
  const byeSpeaker = new Speaker('Bye');

  const names = [
    'Yaakov',
    'John',
    'Jen',
    'Jason',
    'Paul',
    'Frank',
    'Larry',
    'Paula',
    'Laura',
    'Jim',
  ];

  names.forEach((name) => {
    const firstLetter = name.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    const result = firstLetter === 'j' ? byeSpeaker.speak(name) : helloSpeaker.speak(name);
    console.log({result});
  });
})();
```

Your other issue is that your speak function wasn't returning anything, it was returning `undefined` implicitly.

example:

```
function noReturn() {
  console.log('inside noReturn')
  // no return statement, so implicitly it's as though you wrote:
  // return undefined;
}

console.log('noReturn result:', noReturn())
```

Answer (score 1):

You got undefined because you call:

```
console.log(byeSpeaker.speak(names[i]));
console.log(helloSpeaker.speak(names[i]));
```

But its return nothing. That's why you got undefined.
You can fix it. Just call the function, not log it. Like that:

```
byeSpeaker.speak(names[i]))    
helloSpeaker.speak(names[i])
```

Hope you got it.
Thank You

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. it still didn't work though...and Im still getting 'undefined' for names.